# How to save text file as variable in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am sending some images via socket and I would like to create text file with information about the images to send over the network as well.  I right now I can send the images no problem by creating a variable for the image data like so

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(someUIImage, 1.0)
```

How do create a variable with the data of the text file?

```
let textData = someTextFileAsData.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
// Get the URL to the file. Below is an example
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test").appendingPathExtension("txt") // Replace "test" with your fileName and "txt" with your fileExtension
var text = ""

do {
    text = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
} catch {
    fatalError("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`write(to:​ URL, atomically:​ Bool)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1415134-write) or [`write(to​File:​ String, atomically:​ Bool)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1408033-write) of `NSData` method to write your data in a file.

In your case it would be :

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(someUIImage, 1.0)
imageData.writeToFile("imageData.txt", atomically:true)
```

You can then restore it like that :

```
var imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: "imageData.txt")
```

And to get back the image from data :

```
let image : UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Comment: How do I get this data into a variable? Do I read it back after I save it?

Comment: According to your edit, maybe you were requesting for the way to put it back in a UIImage ?

Comment: Oh no the text file has nothing to do with the image, I just want to put general info in the text file like when image was taken etc.  I didn't get a chance to test your code yet I'll update once I get a chance.

Comment: Oooooh i see. Maybe your best bet it to store those info in another file or in NSUserDefaults. You can have imageData1.txt with image data and imageData1-info.txt (or .json) with all informations.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on Anthonin C.'s answer:

Each file in iOS is identified by a `URL` (just like a webpage, but this is a URL referring to the iOS filesystem). There are a few places in the system where you can save files, most of which you can get the URLs for by reading

```
FileManager.default.urls(for: SearchPathDirectory, in: SearchPathDomainMask)
```

([FileManager class reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager)).

For instance, to save in the user's personal "documents" directory, you would do:

```
let fileName = "socketLog.txt"

if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
  //build full path to file
  let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

  do {
      try text.write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
  }
  catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

where `text` would be the string data you want to save.